# Is it mandatory to go back to Activity A that calls startActivityForResult from Activity B?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, start-activity, startactivityforresult

I have two `activities` that I'd like it for them to be able to interact with each other back and forth using the same data but different `views/layout`, and I can perform the same operation in both activities.

I was advised to use `startActivity` instead of `startActivityForResult` because going back to the calling activity (Activity A) is optional, but I don't think that's the way to go.

I've looked and look but everything suggests me to use `startActivityForResult`. If it's possible, then how will not going back to the calling activity will affect the program? Please advise, thanks.

Comment: No, its not mandatory to go back to the previous activity, if you use `startActivityForResult()`, unless you want to handle the result in previous activity (Activity A).

Comment: startActivityForResult is only useful when you want some updated data in onActivityResult() method of existing activity. If you don't require the result then you can simply use the startActivity. If you want something else to achieve please explain what is the actual behaviour you required to achieve.

Comment: @Avi, the data to be exchanged is a list of parcelables and both activities can update the list (edit, remove, add) from both activities and I want it to always be in sync. I think startActivityForResult is the way to go, but the fact that my senior developer suggested to use startActivity, i had to turn here for advise

Comment: Is the list of data is not fetch from any data source like DB or API. And when you update the list aren't they reflected in those data source.

Comment: If you are not updating the datasource then you can use the startActivity with EventBus:- https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus , EvenBus provide you communication between Android component. If you still not able to solve the problem then we can discuss here more.

Comment: You may be better off using a single activity with two Fragments, with the data being held by the Activity. This way you will be actually working on a single data variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not mandatory. The use of `startActivity` and `startActivityForResult` is almost same, except that you 'can' get some data back from Activity B(new activity) if you use `startActivityForResult` with `onActivityResult`.

You can safely ignore the result if you are using `sartActivityForResult` if 
 and you really don't need some data back.

Answer (score 0):

**startActivityForResult()** is useful when you want some updated data from the result of second activity in **onActivityResult()** method of existing activity. If you don't require the result then you can simply use the **startActivity()**. if you don't want any update from second activity than you can simply call **startactivity()** or if you use **startActivityForResult()** than you can ignore intent data from second activity in **onActivityResult()**. You can implement **startActivityForResult()** like this

FirstActivity.java

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 111);
```

SecondActivity.java

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

FirstActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 111) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
          // got result from second activity
            String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Write your code if there's no result
        }
    }
}//onActivityResult
```

Comment: my problem with using startActivityForResult is that during onActivityResult, it will for some reason invoke onCreate again and that will clear all the data that I have received during the callback. Not sure if it's supposed to behave that way.

Comment: What are you doing with `startActivityForResult` ?

Comment: I'm adding an item to the same list from both activities and need to preserve its values in between switching of the activities until a certain action

Comment: Have you tried to add `<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
</activity>`  in manifest file?

Comment: Erm, no. What will that do in my case? I implemented those for preserve state during orientation change but not during activities change.